# How to allocate memory at 100MB boundary?

Tags: windows, memory

On Windows platform, `VitrualAlloc()` function allocate memory at **page boundary**.

```
pMemory = (BYTE*) VirtualAlloc(NULL, size, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
```

Is it possible to allocate memory at given boundary, for example at **100 MB** boundary ?

Comment: 100 MB is not power-of-2 alignment, 128 MB is the better choice.